# Django: Insert row into database

Tags: python, mysql, django, insert

I'm new in Django. I've created a table by insert model into `models.py`.

Now, I want to insert a row into the database - table `Dodavatel`. I know, that I have to create an object with attributes as columns. But I don't know where should I put this code. In `models.py`?

This is my model:

```
class Dodavatel(models.Model):
    nazov = models.CharField(default='', max_length=255)
    dostupnost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is the code for inserting a row:

```
p = Dodavatel(nazov='Petr', dostupnost=1)
p.save()
```

Where should I put this code?

Comment: Create the database by running a "python manage.py syncdb" first. Then, you can add rows according to your model. Normally this is done in the View functions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you only want to quick test your models you can start an interactive shell and execute your code there.

```
python manage.py shell
```

The above command starts a python interactive shell initialized with your Django project settings.

Then you can do something like:

```
from your_app_name.models import Dodavatel
p = Dodavatel(nazov='Petr', dostupnost=1)
p.save()
```

I do not recommend to use that code directly inside a view. Instead to create an item I would use a class based view like `CreateView`.

Comment: I write a script, which would inserting rows into the database. So this is in my script.py: views.add_Dodavatel("petr", 1) and this is in views.py: def add_Dodavatel(nazov,dostupnost):
    p = Dodavatel(nazov=nazov, dostupnost=dostupnost)
    p.save() But when I run the script.py  I get error: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 92, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You should not call a function from your views.py inside a script manually executed. Views should be called by django request-response cycle. If you want to create a script to insert bulk data in your db you should look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 2):

**For manual inserting data to table for testing purpose**

### Method1

[image]

**Execute this command for creating Dodavatel in the database**

```
 python manage.py makemigrations


 python manage.py migrate
```

[image]

**Now you can see the table created in the database**

[image]

**Then type for open python project REPL:**

```
python manage.py shell
```

**add this code in the repl**

```
from everych.cheese.models import Dodavatel

 dodavel = Dodavatel.objects.create(nazov="hi", dostupnost=3)
```

You can use `python manage.py shell_plus` instead of `python manage.py shell`.so you didn't want to add the line `from everych. cheese. models import Dodavatel` it automatically imported.

here *everych* my project name

cheese is the application name

change as your project and application name

[image]

**After the above code is executed data will be inserted into the table**
**output:-**
[image]

### Method2

Here just inserting data you must add a table using the above step.

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

[image]
**code**

```
dat = Dodavatel(nazov="Petr", dostupnost=1)
dat.save()
```

[image]
Output:

[image]

Comment: manage.py always in the root of the project .so the terminal must be in the root folder